# Querying for a pointer attribute using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im developing an app with User and Request as classes on Parse. My Users have currentLocation (PFGeoPoint) as an attribute and Requests have a pointer to refer the User that owns the request (requestor:PFUser). So Im trying to find requests from users near to the current user logged in.

I need to do something like:

```
let currentUserGeoPoint = PFUser.currentUser()!["currentLocation"] as! PFGeoPoint

var query = PFQuery(className:"Request")
query.whereKey("requestor.currentLocation", nearGeoPoint: currentUserGeoPoint)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (objects, error) -> Void in
          if (error == nil) {
             self.userRequests = objects!
             self.tableView.reloadData()
          }else {
             println(error?.userInfo)
          }
}
```

But unfortunatelly this is not possible:

```
[Error]: Dot notation can only be used on objects (Code: 102, Version: 1.8.1)
Optional([code: 102, error: Dot notation can only be used on objects, temporary: 0, NSLocalizedDescription: Dot notation can only be used on objects])
```

Any ideas?

This is how my Request Class looks like on Parse:

[image]

This is the User Class:

[image]

Comment: The `dot notation` part of your error message leads me to believe that the `requestor` in your `whereKey` is not an object, i.e. you cannot call currentLocation on a non-object ("requestor.currentLocation"). Can you check that ?

Comment: Can you show the user class as well ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this question](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfquery-using-dot-notation-for-wherekeyequalto) in the Parse Community:

> Instead of dot notation in whereKey:, you would use whereKey:matchesKey:inQuery: or whereKey:matchesQuery:.